# Debug XML sent to Web Service

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services, debugging

VB2010: IT has developed a web service and provided me with a WSDL. I've imported that into my project to define the service. In test and stage that is working pretty good. Having some issues in production so am looking to see if there is a way that I can see the final XML request being sent to the service. Not sure where I can add my debug statements to print it out.

Comment: Just use fiddler or some other network/http sniffer.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping for an in-project way to do this. It's possible that IT will not allow us to install a sniffer. But I'll give it a shot.

Comment: As @OldProgrammer has said, fiddler is awesome. I would try to convince IT to allow it if possible